# Out of Memory Exception after publishing to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, performance, out-of-memory

Q:

I face the following problem after I publish my application on IIS :

sometimes the application hang then when i try to refresh i get `resource not found`.

I check my error folder : and i find more than one reference to the following exception

`Out of Memory Exception`.

I read data from `xml` file and split them to insert later in my database equivalent tables.

I retrieve the data from xml through LINQ :

Like this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("c:\\test.xml");
            var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("User")
                    select (string)c.Attribute("FirstName") + "■" + (string)c.Attribute("LastName")+ "■" + (string)c.Attribute("age");


foreach (string name in q)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        string substring = name.Split('■')[i];
                    }
                }
```

## Notes :

- The number of records in each node `q` may reach 2000 records.
- The number of fields separated by `■` about 7 at maximum .(for each
  record)
- I have about ten entities (i mean about ten `q` i process on).

Please How to redesign my code quickly to solve this fatal problem especially this is happened with one user what if more than one user let's say 100 user in parallel !!!

Comment: Is it really separated by a square or is it just my view that looks like that?

Comment: Why would you concatenate them then immediately split them?  Why not just select to an anonymous object?

Comment: no  i decided to use square as a separator to guarantee that the it doesn't exist in the xml file.no one will use square in the xml file but may use `,` or `_` or `-` ...etc.

Does this make some problem?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham:please more clarification (code if possible).I get about 1000 to 2000 record in `q` then i loop through each record to get each field(attribute value).

Comment: @ Asken :yeah it 's a square.

Comment: This is the Internet. Assuming people won't put strange characters in their name is definitely not a valid assumption! ;)

Comment: hmmm, I put an example but this is not the real part of xml , so the user may use `*`,`,or some special character int the keyboard , so to avoid this , i used the square.

Comment: If I *really* wanted to do that, I'd use a non-character that isn't valid in Unicode text and therefore not valid in XML, e.g. U+FFFE or U+FFFF. That can't possibly be in any well-formed XML sent so it can't clash. Still, there's no need to do this joining anyway as people said.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will try to refactor my code to be wise performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are finding that use of `XDocument` is expensive in memory (and from your description it would seem that you **might** be, though the issue could be elsewhere), then it could well be worth replacing its use with a forward-only reader that doesn't store linked lists of child nodes:

```
private struct UserNode
{
  public string FirstName{get;private set;}
  public string LastName{get;private set;}
  public int Age{get;private set;}
  public UserNode(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Age = age;
  }
}

private static IEnumerable<UserNode> ReadUserNodes(string filePath)
{
  using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
  using(XmlReader xrdr = new XmlTextReader(fs))
    while(xrdr.Read())
      if(xrdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xrdr.LocalName == "User")
        yield return new UserNode(xrdr.GetAttribute("FirstName"), xrdr.GetAttribute("LastName"), int.Parse(xrdr.GetAttribute("age")));
}

/*...*/

foreach(UserNode user in ReadUserNodes(@"c:\test.xml"))
{
  //Do something useful with users...
}
```

It's impossible with this do do something like examine the `Parent` or `PreviousNode` property for a given element, but you aren't doing that anyway, so who cares? Because the data needed to examine such properties isn't maintained in memory the memory usage is much less.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve all the memory issues you're having, but you shouldn't concatenate string then immediately split them.  You should use an anonymous object for your query instead:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("c:\\test.xml");
var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("User")
        select new
        {
            FirstName = (string)c.Attribute("FirstName"),
            LastName = (string)c.Attribute("LastName"),
            Age = (string)c.Attribute("age")
        };

foreach (var user in q)
{
    // This just shows how to access the properties.
    // You can do whatever else you want with them at this point
    Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine(user.LastName);
    Console.WriteLine(user.Age);
}
```

String concatenation and string splitting are both relatively expensive operations, as is loading a large XML document into memory.  Doing all together *could* contribute to the problem you're seeing, though it is really hard to tell from this context.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I hope this will decrease the memory consumption.
I also use `RadUploader`(telerik control), Does this may consume the memory as a third party?

Comment: @just_name: I don't have experience with their `RadUploader`, but I guess it could.  If you need to reduce memory consumption, I suggest you use a profiler such as [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) or [the CLR profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) against your code, and track memory usage statistics that way.